# Mounting .img error: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: linux, operating-system, centos

I tried to write a simple operating system and started with a boot.asm.
Firstly I used

```
#nasm boot.asm -o boot.bin
```

to compile the source and then used

```
#dd conv=sync if=boot.bin of=os.img bs=512 count=1
```

to make a .img file. I used VMware to run this img and succeeded in booting.

Now I want to add loader.bin into this .img so Firstly I use

```
#losetup /dev/loop1 os.img
```

to set it as loop device. Then

```
#mount /dev/loop1 /tmp
```

. However, an error occurred:

```
mount: /tmp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Here are some details about os.img:

```
#file os.img
os.img: DOS/MBR boot sector
#fdisk -l  os.img
Disk os.img: 512 B, 512 bytes, 1 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
os.img1          778530409 2158795926 1380265518 658.2G 42 SFS
os.img2         1145130828 2321654160 1176523333   561G 20 unknown
os.img3         1109414469 1109434509      20041   9.8M 4c unknown
```

Comment: Is it possible to share boot.asm, and how you run os.img with VMWare ?

Comment: @Philippe Here is my repositories: [link](https://github.com/Mizuyusan/First_OS). And the specific way is to create a VM(Sys: Others; Edition: Others), add a virtual floppy disk in this VM and then choose os.img as floppy image.

Comment: On my VMWare Workstation 16 Player, I don't have "virtual floppy disk".

Comment: @Philippe I also use Vmware Workstation 16. Firstly you should create such VM(Sys: Others; Edition: Others). By default there is no floppy in VM, but we can add it in VM configuration(at the bottom of that window is a button "add", click it and choose floppy disk)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the file system, run following commands one by one in bash/root.

```
img=diskimage.img
cd /tmp 
dd if=/dev/zero of=$img bs=1048576 count=128
fdisk $img <<< $'g\nn p\n1\n2048\n+8M\nt 1\n1\nw'
# You need to change "LOADER BIN" to "LOADER.BIN" in boot.asm. Compile loader.asm to LOADER.BIN
dd if=boot.bin of=$img conv=notrunc bs=446 count=1 
dd if=boot.bin of=$img conv=notrunc bs=1 count=2 skip=510 seek=510
loop=$(losetup --show -o $((2048*512)) --sizelimit $((16*1024*1024)) -f $img)
echo "loop device is $loop"
mkfs.vfat -F 16 -n "EFI System" $loop
mount=/tmp/boot; mkdir -p $mount
mount $loop $mount
cp LOADER.BIN $mount/ 
umount $mount
losetup -d $loop
```

Now you can use diskimage.img in VMWare as floppy disk.